# How to update post author after update post

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to update post_author after update post by getting current user ID, but when I use this function wordpress created new post with correct author  by copied current post

```
function change_author () {
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

        $post= array(
            'ID'            => $post_id,
            'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
        );

        wp_update_post( $post );


    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'change_author');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the [wp_insert_post_data hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/) instead of `save_post`. Rather than updating the post after it's saved, it's probably better to change the data before it gets inserted into the database as part of the save post action. Here's what I'd do:

```php
function change_author ( $data ) {
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $data['ID'] ) ){
        $data['post_author'] = get_current_user_id();
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'change_author', 10, 1 );
```